# How to automatically start xampp control panel in Win 8?

Tags: windows-8, boot, xampp, control-panel

I can't figure out where to enable the xampp control panel start on Win 8 start up.
I looked under services but I don't see an option there.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the executable for the XAMPP Control Panel is **xampp-control.exe** in your main XAMPP installation folder.

1. Press <kbd>[image: Win]</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to open the Run dialog and type `shell:startup`:

   [image: 2]

   This will take you to the `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` folder.
2. Simply create a shortcut there to the program and it should start up automatically with Windows.

   [image: 3]