# Install Visual Studio 2012 (and SQL Server 2012) on SD card

Tags: installation, sd-card

I have a tablet/netbook (Acer W511) which I use for work when I'm not at home. It's great computer overall, but it have only 32GB on a hard drive so I get a 64GB SD card to increase allowed space.
But I've found that Visual Studio 2012 couldn't be installed on SD card as well as SQL Server 2012.

Is there some workaround?

Comment: Why can't it be installed on an SD card? Do you get an error message? (if so, which one, post it). Does it complain about removable media? (If so, set the card to non removable). What happens if you mount the SD card in a subdirectory rather than with a drive letter? ...

Comment: Sorry, yes, I receive error message "The path entered cannot be on a removable drive". I'll try to mount SD card in a subdirectory, thank you!

Comment: Check this out [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6853375/how-can-i-install-visual-studio-into-a-removable-media-like-dvd)

Comment: @Hennes your solution to mount SD card to a subdirectory works fine (at least for SQL Server), could you write it as an answer so I'll accept it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use NTFS you can not just mount a volume with a drive letter; you can also mount it in a directory.  (Similar to the way unices mount their filesystem).

To do this go to [start] [run] and type `diskmgmt.msc`.
Select the disk you want to modify and right click on it.
Choose "Change drive letters or paths..."

[image: Win7 disk management.msc]

If you have a previously assigned drive letter then use the [remove] button to get rid of it. Then use [add] and select "mount in the following NTFS folder"

[image]

Comment: It's 2020 and we haven't figured that one out yet. Writing from 128GB Surface "Pro".

Answer (score 3):

[image: 1]

Visual Studio 2012 indeed refuses to install on removable drives, but it *can* be installed on certified [Windows To Go](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_To_Go) devices. A list of such devices can be found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/enterprise/products-and-technologies/devices/windowstogo.aspx) and [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831833#wtg_hardware).

If you don't have such a device then one *possible* workaround (which I haven't personally tried) might be to create a [VHD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VHD_%28file_format%29) on the card and install the programs in that. The performance might be terrible, but that's for you to deal with.

Open **Disk Management** (`Run / diskmgmt.msc`) and create a VHD on the card from the **Action** menu. **Initialise** the new disk, create a new **simple volume** on it, **format** as NTFS and specify a **drive letter.**

To auto-mount the VHD/VHDX you can [create a shortcut in your startup folder](https://superuser.com/a/613442/138343) or use the Task Scheduler/Group Policy Editor to schedule a startup/logon script that runs the following command:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe Mount-DiskImage "VHD_Drive:\path to\VHD.vhd"
```

Comment: +1 thank you, I've found @Hennes solution a little bit simplier